# Can't remove margin space above my navigation

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML   Can someone please help me?  I can't remove the little margin above the navigation.

I've already tried padding:0px and margin-top:0px

```
            <body>

            <div id="wrap">
                <div class="top_portion">
                <img src="img/icbox.png">
                </div>

            <div id="welcome">
                <h1>Welcome to my blog about the married life</h1>
                <h3>Ain't much to see here for now!</h3>
            </div>

            <div id="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#Home">Home</li>
                    <li><a href="#About">About</li>
                    <li><a href="#Pictures">Pictures</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

AND THIS IS THE CSS Sorry it's been a while since I've been back to this website

```
body    {
    background-color:white;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
}

.top_portion    {
    width:800px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#e2e2e2;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:5px;
    border-bottom:5px;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#30474b;
}

.top_portion    img     {
    padding-top:35px;
}

#welcome    h1  {
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

#welcome    h3  {
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

#welcome    {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#e2e2e2;
    width:800px;
}

#navigation {
    text-align:center;
}

#navigation li  {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
}

ul  {
    margin-top:0;
}

ul a {
    padding-right:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul a:hover  {
    text-decoration:underline;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the **h3** 
`Margin:0;` does the trick.. Where did you aply the `margin:0;` earlier?

```
h3 {margin:0;}
```

In your case you should change your `#welcome h3` to:

```
#welcome h3 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aG5Ta/2)**

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thank you!  It's crazy I thought margin-top:0px would do the trick I wonder how come it didn't! :(

Comment: No problem, a good trick to avoid all default margin and paddings. Use this `*{margin:0; padding:0;`

Comment: It wasn't identical, because you uses `margin-bottom:0;` and i use `margin:0;` so he can delete `margin-top:0;` and `margin-bottom:0;` using it in 1. cleaner css...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

I think its because of the default behavior of Heading.

## Style:

```
    html, body 
    {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
    }
    #welcome h3 {
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    /*Or you can try
    #welcome h3 {
        margin:0;
        text-align: center;
    }*/
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XCbRx/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove margin from the top for your navigation bar you could possibly try this:

```
#navigation {
margin-top: 0px;
border-top: 0px;
}
```

As, you are including list in your navigation it may eat up some of your space too. Try including this:

```
#navigation li {
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Possibly, you can also try for:

```
#welcome h3 {
margin: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

H3, because this would hold just the line above your navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

I have changed these things in your query

```
    #navigation {
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:0px;
    }

#welcome h1 {
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;

}
#welcome h3 {
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align:center;
     margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

## [workingFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5uMz/1/)